# Does "job nature" mean "job circumstances and surroundings"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-request

I don't know if there is such a phrase exists, but I translated it literally from my native language to English. So, I would like to know if it is correct and means "job circumstances and surroundings".

The sentence I want to use that *phrase* in:

> She has to be in an appearance that is consistent with her **job nature**,
>   so she can do it perfectly as you claimed.

I searched for it on the web but found nothing except the phrase "job description" which is a document that describes the general tasks, or other related duties.

---

**PS:** X is saying that sentence to Y about Z who works as a chef. What X means by the sentence (not my personal opinion) is that Z can't wear a full face of makeup and let her long hair down, when she is working in the kitchen because of the nature of her job.

Comment: **Job nature** is not natural - usually just **job** is sufficient to encompass not just duties, but also circumstances and surroundings.  Also, what exactly are you trying to get at with "appearance"?  It sounds like you're saying that how someone looks or dresses is essential to her doing the job perfectly, which is an odd thing to say. Was that your intended meaning?  If not, then "appearance" might be the wrong word.

Comment: @CanadianYankee - You have a point, but I want to emphasize the nature of her job since I'm not talking about her job in general. About the **appearance**, I have updated my question. Thank you.

Comment: I still don't like **appearance** in this situation, since that word is specifically about how someone **appears to others**. You could use it for a server at themed restaurant, for example ("her appearance must be consistent with the cowboy theme"), but not for hygienic requirements like wearing a hairnet. **Attire** is more neutral in that it refers directly to clothes and not to how those close appear to others.

Comment: I have to disagree, sorry. I want it to be about everything about Z, from her hair, makeup, to her clothes. If I used "attire" I would talk about the latter. Thus, I will go with "She has to **present an appearance** that is consistent with **the nature of her job**, so she can do it **well** as you claimed.". I appreciate the word suggestion, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "job description" is a quite formal part of a contract or job advertisement that gives details of what exactly is required.

It is hard to understand the example sentence.  I don't understand "She has to be in an appearance", and the phrase "job nature" is not idiomatic. 
You can say "She has to *present an appearance..."

Insted of "job nature" you can use "the nature of her job".  In this context "nature" means roughly "type", and could include the tasks, the environment and the circumstances of the job.

> What is the nature of your job?
>   It's an office job. I work with a small team of colleagues. We work on computers, contacting foreign clients.

Comment: Yes, **the nature of her job** is pretty accurate to what I wanted to use in the sentence. I have updated my question to what I meant by it. Thanks for the answer.